# Why go/doc doesn't provide the methods?

Tags: go

I'm trying to extract the documentation for various functions an methods using the [go/doc](http://golang.org/src/go/doc) package. The code looks pretty much as below. The issue is that it prints/provides only the functions from the package(exported and unexported) but no method regardless if they're exported or unexported. I also tried `AllMethods` mode with no success. Is this a bug or I'm missing something?

```
pkg := doc.New(mainPkg, "./", doc.AllDecls)

for _, vv := range pkg.Funcs {
    log.Infof("vv.Name %v, vv.Recv %v", vv.Name,  vv.Recv,  )

}
```

Comment: You need to extract the methods from iterating the types, not the funcs.

Comment: Yeah...I've just started working on this...

Comment: maybe post the way to do it as an answer when you figure it out

Comment: The methods are available in the Types field (which doesn't seems right to me) so I'm not sure if it's worth an answer.

Comment: It seems perfectly right to me - the methods belong to types, not to the package itself. but if it confused you it might confuse others, so an answer would be good.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer, I entirely agree. OP - a package only exports constants, variables, functions and types. The first three are exactly what they sound like, types is where it gets fun. Struct types, which is what you're looking for, are the ones who know about what functions return them (i.e. "constructors") and what methods they receive (methods called on them).

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through `pkg.Types` and on each item you can get its [Methods](http://localhost:6060/pkg/go/doc/#Type).

```
type Type struct {
  Doc  string
  Name string
  Decl *ast.GenDecl

  // associated declarations
  Consts  []*Value // sorted list of constants of (mostly) this type
  Vars    []*Value // sorted list of variables of (mostly) this type
  Funcs   []*Func  // sorted list of functions returning this type
  Methods []*Func  // sorted list of methods (including embedded ones) of this type
}
```